# WooCommerce Internal Server Error when category is empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, internal-server-error

After upgradeing from 4.8.3 to 5.2.3 I am facing the following issue: when a category does not contain any of products, it runs to Internal Server Error. I have tested it multiple hosting providers. Everything fine except this.

Has anyone faced this issue already?

**UPDATE:** This issue is related to WooCommerce Product Filter plugin. If I deactivate it, site works properly.

Comment: Welcome, @G. Gréczi! If you post the error logs as they relate to this, I'm sure someone will be able to help you along the way to a solution. And, perhaps, some excerpts or links to the source code corresponding to files mentioned in the logs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The million dollar solution:**
Drop this files: 
/wp-content/plugins/prdcfltr/woocommerce/loop/no-products-found.php
/wp-content/plugins/prdcfltr/woocommerce/loop/product-filter-no-products-found.php

Topic should be closed.